# How to save a .txt document as an excel file without changing its type(.txt)

Tags: excel

I have a requirement where I need a text file to be open/saved as an Excel file, but its type should remain unchanged(.txt). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: In Windows, the file extension dictates how the file is to be opened. In this case, you could use "Open with..." and select Excel as the default program for `.txt` files, but I am not sure that this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's saved as an excel file that becomes its type. No there is no way to Achive this

Comment: Thank you! the user was notified and requirement was changed.